# No versions available for org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32:x86_64:jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, native, piccolo

While trying to depend on `piccolo2d-swt-examples` artifact (in `m2e`), I am getting the following message

```
VersionRangeResolutionException: No versions available for org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32:x86_64:jar:[3.3.0-v3346,) within 
 specified range
```

What is the meaning of this message? Does it mean that there is no library for win32 at all? Or it means that `SWT` is not under maven control?

**UPDATE**

My current `POM` is below.

Currently it has no any explicit dependency on `SWT`. Being not fluent with Maven, I can't judge if this message means, that Maven feels my `SWT` version from global settings and reports, that no library written for it, or it just can't find any required SWT libraries in repository.

In first case I can't use SWT version of Piccolo at all (it is not portable, since not written for all platforms) while in second case I can use it, but need to pack SWT for Maven in local repository.

This is the question.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>Piccolo2D_3_Tests</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.piccolo2d</groupId>
            <artifactId>piccolo2d-swt-examples</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you want to build a 64 bit application? If not, I'd try to add `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32:x86:3.3.0-v3346` to the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

```
VersionRangeResolutionException: No versions available for   
org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32:x86_64:jar:[3.3.0-v3346,) within specified range
```

According to a [maven central query](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32%22%20AND%20a%3A%22x86_64%22) there is no x86_64 artifact for that swt jar file but [there is an x86 artifact](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32%22%20AND%20a%3A%22x86%22).

You might want to try forcing your piccolo2d dependency to activate its `windows_x86` profile explicity using `mvn -Pwindows_x86` or (*UPDATE 2*) try building with a 32-bit Java JDK.

*UPDATE 1*: Your problems look similar to piccolo [Issue 203: Missing maven profile for Windows x86_64](http://code.google.com/p/piccolo2d/issues/detail?id=203).

Comment: Why doesn't it say "missing artifact"?

Comment: That would be a question for the maven developers.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the the missing artifact from here(http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgeclipseswtwin32win32x866442jar.htm) and installed the jar using
 `>mvn install:install-file -Dfile=org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64-4.2.jar -DgroupId=org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32 -DartifactId=x86_64 -Dversion=4.2 -Dpackaging=jar`

 And it started working fine :)

PS: This way you don't need to tamper with the profiles at all.

Comment: I would download the SWT implementation from the official eclipse [archive](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) site instead. Download the [swt-3.4.zip](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/download.php?dropFile=swt-3.4-win32-win32-x86_64.zip), unpack it and use the internal swt.jar file.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [Piccolo readme](http://piccolo2d.googlecode.com/svn/piccolo2d.java/tags/release-1.3.1/Readme.txt):

```
To include the Piccolo2D core classes in your project, use a
dependency of

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.piccolo2d</groupId>
  <artifactId>piccolo2d-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

in your pom.xml. To include the Piccolo2D core classes and the
Piccolo2D extras classes in your project, use a dependency of

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.piccolo2d</groupId>
  <artifactId>piccolo2d-extras</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

in your pom.xml. To include the Piccolo2D core classes and the
Piccolo2D SWT classes in your project, use a dependency of

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.piccolo2d</groupId>
  <artifactId>piccolo2d-swt</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Does adding these dependencies change anything?

Comment: No. Last artifact is most probably depends on first two, so they are included automatically by Maven nature.

Comment: Another piece from the readme: `For some platforms, including Mac OSX with JDK version 1.6 or
later on x86_64, the Eclipse Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT) version
3.3.0 or later must also be installed manually. Eclipse Standard Widget Toolkit
http://www.eclipse.org/swt/`

Comment: It is downloaded and referred by "external jar" means of Eclipse. I can compile and run standalone SWT classes if without Maven.